# Laravel, pass the value when press button

Tags: php, laravel

I have a modal pop out when pressing a button. Problem is, how do pass the value to the modal?

My table as shown in figure below. As you can see each row have different id. I wanted to get the id of a particular row after pressed the button

[image]

**my code:**

```
@foreach($company as $cmp)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $cmp->number }}</td>
  <td>{{ $cmp->name}}</td>
  <td>  <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" </td
</tr>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the modal too but in a separate view, the `id` needs to be called from your `$cmp` `var` in order to dynamically assign the HTML `id` of the modal and the trigger button:

```
@foreach($company as $cmp)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $cmp->number }}</td>
  <td>{{ $cmp->name}}</td>
  <td>  <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal{{$cmp->id}}" </td
</tr>
@include('path.modal')//Path of the view of a modal
@endforeach
```

In a separate view:

```
<!-- modal.blade.php -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal{{$cmp->id}}"role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i followed exactly what you posted, it seems that my modal is not showing

Comment: Check your modal view file, this will work if your $cmp var has an id

Comment: Also check with inspect element in your browser if you have multiple modals

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Bootstrap for your layouts.
[Documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) suggests you to bind `data-` attributes to pass values to your modal.
You can use jQuery to handle the `show.bs.modal` event for this.

You should add unique identifier to your button. For example `data-modal-id`. Like this:

```
@foreach($company as $cmp)
<tr>
     <td>{{ $cmp->number }}</td>
     <td>{{ $cmp->name }}</td>
     <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-modal-id="{{ $cmp->number }}">Button</button>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And in your javascript:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var modal_id = button.data('modal-id');;
  var modal = $(this);
  // do whatever you want with your modal and modal_id
});
```

Comment: is there any alternative way without using javascript?

Comment: You could create different modals for each button with unique ids that would have corresponding `data-target` attributes. But I think this is not the best approach.